# Validate State of Checkbox using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, checkbox, robotframework

I am trying to determine the state of checkboxes on page load, and if they are not checked, to check them.  My goal is to establish a known state before proceeding to test the page.

I am using a `run keyword unless` keyword with a variable:

```
***Variable***  
${checked1}  checkbox should be selected  xpath=(//input[@name='allowfields'])[2]
${checked2}  checkbox should be selected  xpath=(//input[@name='allowsharing'])[2]  

***Test Cases***
Validate checkbox initial state
Run Keyword unless  ${checked1}  Click Element  xpath=(//input[@name='allowfields'])[2]
Run Keyword unless  ${checked2}  Click Element  xpath=(//input[@name='allowsharing'])[2]
```

The tests are currently erring out with a message of:
Evaluating expression 'checkbox should be selected xpath=(//input[@name='allowfields'])[2]' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Edit Below...
Thanks to @Mohanapriya I was able to parse through the code and came up with a partial solution.  The automation runs and returns PASS, but does not change the state of the checkbox from unchecked to checked.

Here is what I have partially working:

```
*** Keyword ***  
Configure Checkbox  
[Arguments]  ${Status_Locator}  ${Checkbox_Locator}  ${Excel_Value}  
${Is_Checkbox_Selected}  Run Keyword And Return Status  Checkbox Should Be Selected  ${Status_Locator}  ${Actual_Chkbx_Value}  Run Keyword If '${Is_Checkbox_Selected}'== 'True'  Set Variable  Yes  else if '${Is_Checkbox_Selected}'== 'False'  Set Variable  No  Log  ${Actual_Chkbx_Value}  Run Keyword If '${Excel_Value}'!='${Actual_Chkbx_Value}'  Click Element ${Checkbox_Locator}  
Click Button    css=button.primary.success
```

At the point of failure, ride log shows:
`Starting test: Tests.Validate checkbox state
20170117 12:29:16.968 :  FAIL : Variable '${Is_Checkbox_Selected}' not found.
20170117 12:29:16.969 :  INFO : ${Is_Checkbox_Selected} = False
20170117 12:29:16.971 :  INFO : Clicking button 'css=button.primary.success'.`

Any feedback on how to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Configure Checkbox
    [Arguments]    ${Status_Locator}    ${Checkbox_Locator}    ${Excel_Value}
    ${Is_Checkbox_Selected}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Checkbox Should Be Selected    ${Status_Locator}
    ${Actual_Chkbx_Value}=    Run Keyword If    '${Is_Checkbox_Selected}'== 'True'    Set Variable    Yes
    ...    ELSE IF    '${Is_Checkbox_Selected}'== 'False'    Set Variable    No
    Log    ${Actual_Chkbx_Value}
    Run Keyword If    '${Excel_Value}'!='${Actual_Chkbx_Value}'    Click Element    ${Checkbox_Locator}
```

In this code i have passed three arguments.

Comment: Hi Mohanapriya, is Configure Checkbox a local library, or part of a different robot library?  Your code formatting makes it difficult to determine.

Comment: @CharlesRamsell, Configure Checkbox is a user defined keyword (local library)